# my code is flagging an error at the elevatedbutton and if statement

Tags: flutter, dart, styling, conditional-operator

```dart
child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>((Set<MaterialState> State){}
                    )),
                      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
                      return Colors.green;
                    child: Text('Add task',style: GoogleFonts.roboto(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {})),}
```

The if statement is flagging an error and my if statement too

I have not try anything yet.

Comment: Do we have to guess what the error is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on bad shape, It can be like

```dart
child: ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
        (Set<MaterialState> states) {
      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) return Colors.green;
      return Colors.white;
    }),
  ),
  child: Text(
    'Add task',
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```